# MongoDb database Filter is not working in Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

When I query all the records, i get the results as shown below.
[image]

When i copy an ID from the result and add it in the filter, no result is found.

[image]

Here is the example filter from documentation
[image]

What am i doing wrong? mongo db got to be kidding me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing the data type with the query. Since your _id field is **ObjectId** type and you are comparing as string that is why it is not working.
Change your filter condition and convert your string id to ObjectId type.

```
{_id: ObjectId('yourId')}
```

MongoDB provides an automatic unique identifier for the _id field in the form of an ObjectId data type.